# Adding two or more tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have table A and table B, i want table C to have the sum of the data from table A and B and any other tables that i create. All tables have the same structure. ( same type of date) I want table C to display the sum of of each row on its respective column.

So you can have a better understanding of what i am asking for. i am using the table to keep track of baseball scores, adding different games result into a table so it calculates baseball' statistics.

Table A
[image]

Table B
[image]

I want table see to add the results.

Example.  I want table C to in the first line to have this values.

Angel Ceballo   P  AB   1B   2B   3B  HR  AVG  K  ER RBI R OUT HIPD

```
            SS 18  4  2  0  2  444  0  6  6  8  10   0
```

any help will be really appreciated !!

Comment: why you need to save the data into another new table, this is redundancy data, and this is not best practice.

Comment: and what is the provider that you uses, SQL Server or MySQL ??

Comment: I am using my php, to get the data from the database, i use mysql. The reason that i need a third table is because i want to combine the sum of both table into one. let say i have person 1 from table A who has 2 apples, i have the same person 1 and table B who has 4 apples; i want table C to say that person 1 has 6 apples. combining the total of both tables. Thank you

Comment: You can reach to ur target via Selecting & Join ....somting Like That ... select a.colName + b.colName from table1 a , table2 b where a.PersonID = b.PersonID

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but look at the pics I submitted from the table I want to join . The solution you gave me only work for the example I provided